# SharePoint 2010 connectable webparts

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I wanted to create a custom webpart with acts as both consumer and provider.

So I want my custom webpart to act as a bridge between two OOB sharepoint webparts.

WP1 -> **WP2** -> WP3

I want to get the data from WP1 and wanted it to manupulate it and then send it to WP3 for filtering.

My issues are :

1. I want the provider to provide data to WP3 only after WP1 send the data to consumer. Is that possible ?
2. How can I send the data (received from WP1) from consumer class to provider class ?

Can anybody help ? or can suggest some alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement both the consumer and the provider interfaces on the web part.  This will allow both of the OOB webparts to talk to your web part.  Since WP2 won't be sending a value until you set a filter, WP3 will probably display everything; to work around that you will have to set the default value that WP2 sends to WP3 to something that will force not data to appear (what that value is depends on what webparts you are using).  Some sort of null value will probably work.  That help?